# Convertir de codigo ASCII ampliado a caracter

Tags: vb.net, ascii, serialport

Tengo un programa en VB.Net que lee del puerto serie los carácteres que le van llegando:

```
serialPort = My.Computer.Ports.OpenSerialPort(leerPuerto())
serialPort.BaudRate = 9600
serialPort.Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
serialPort.StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One
serialPort.DataBits = 8
serialPort.Handshake = IO.Ports.Handshake.None
serialPort.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591)
caracter = serialPort.ReadChar
```

Veo que interpreta de forma errónea los caracácteres y me devuelve lo siguiente: ¶3fÌ27 se que está intentando devolverme el valor 0.0027 pero no es capaz de transformar el primer caracter en simbolo negativo o positivo.

En cambio si del puerto serie leo el byte que me devuelve y lo transformo en char mediante la tabla ascii ampliada, vemos que el númerp 43 corresponde: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo convertir el codigo 43 al caracter correspondiente de dicha tabla?

Comment: hmm..te refieres a `Chr(43)`?

Comment: No funciona, sigue enviando un caracter no printable

Comment: A ver...`Chr(43)` te devuelve el caracter `+`, eso es seguro. La cuestión es que no termino de entender cual es tu problema. Podrías poner el código que estás usando y te falla, o, mejor aun, un [mcve]?

Comment: He actualizado el codigo y me devuelve ¶3fÌ25

Comment: Supongo que estás leyendo de algun dispositivo conectado al puerto serie. El problema es que estas usando `ReadChar` cuando probablemente lo que debas hacer es usar `ReadByte` o `Read` para obtener los datos "en crudo" y luego convertir a char o a lo que sea.`ReadChar` está intentando convertir a char un dato que (ya que dices que por ejemplo puede ser 0.0027) no lo es.Sin mas información, es complicado poder ayudarte mas.

Comment: Ahora uso readbyte y luego para ver el caracter uno a uno uso chr para convertirlo a caracter "imprimible" y uno a uno me muestra: ->¶ -> ->3 -> ->f ->Ì ->7 ->1

Comment: si muestro la cadena de bytes: ->182 ->25 ->51 ->25 ->102 ->204 ->53 ->48 ->13

Comment: No comentas que dispositivo es el que te está enviando los datos. Puede ser que tenga un protocolo de comunicación definido, y en ese caso debes ver la documentación para ver de que manera está enviando los datos.Por otro lado, en lugar de leer los datos uno a uno, tal vez deberías usar el evento `DataReceived` para que los datos se vayan recibiendo a medida que van llegando.

Comment: El protocolo que se usa en el dispositivo es, yo envio la cadena #010 y me devuelve un valor double pero en string, entonces al no poder representar dicha cadena no puedo luego transformarla a double...